# How to fix "ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist" in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I’m trying to **CREATE TABLE** command in Postgresql. 
After creating a table, if I punch in **TABLE** *table name*, it works.

But I punch in **\d** *table name*, I keep getting an error below.

`ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...`

I attempted **DROP DATABASE** *table name* recreated a database and recreated a table again several times. But it didn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: It was solved! Thank you so much everyone!

locate pg_hba.conf 
createdb Nao

Then it worked.

Comment: Simple solution that worked is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58462270/984471

Comment: What do you mean by " if I punch in TABLE table name, it works. "

Comment: @Nao what did you do to solve it?

Answer (score 127):

I am able to reproduce your error if I am using Postgres v.12 and an older client (v.11 or earlier):

```
[root@def /]# psql -h 172.17.0.3
psql (11.5, server 12.0)
WARNING: psql major version 11, server major version 12.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create table mytable (id int, name text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# table mytable;
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)

postgres=# \d mytable;
ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...
                                                             ^
postgres=#
```

This is because in v. 12, [table OIDs are no longer treated as special columns](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/04/24/oid-column.html), and hence the `relhasoids` column is no longer necessary.  Please make sure you're using a v. 12 `psql` binary so you don't encounter this error.

You may not necessarily be using `psql`, so the more general answer here is to make sure you’re using a compatible client.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am using v11.5... I'll try to uninstall and reinstall postgress again.

Comment: This answer led me to the culprit in my case: I have multiple PgAdmin installations, and Windows search was only giving me an old one to use. Therefore I was using an old PgAdmin with a Postgres v12.

Answer (score 50):

For anyone running *Postgres* as a *Docker* container:

Instead of running *psql* from the host, run it from inside the container e.g.

```
docker exec -it postgres_container_name psql your_connection_string
```

The [Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) image always ships with the corresponding—and thus always updated—version of *psql* so you don't have to worry about having the correct version installed on the host machine.

Comment: That really misses the point. You need to be able to access a container independently.

Comment: I’m not sure what “accessing a container independently” means in this context or why the command in my reply is somehow not allowing that?

Comment: Because having to directly access the container may not always be possible. The problem here seems to require a separate postgres service.  Downgrading the psql client, or upgrading the server is the solution; not simply bypassing the problem and running it together. That is not always possible due to other architectural constraints.

Comment: Of course; I did not suggest using Docker *as a solution*. That’s why I led with “For anyone running Postgres as a Docker container”.

Comment: Can you please post an example of "your_connection_string"?

Comment: Hey Olle. That would be whatever options you would pass to psql. For example, today I had to run the above with “... psql -U testuser” to authenticate as a specific user

Answer (score 32):

If you're using DataGrip, there's an easy fix:

Try using "Introspect using JDBC metadata". This fixed it for me when (I think) I had a  version mismatch between postgresql server and DataGrip client.

Under your connection settings -> Options tab -> check Introspect using JDBC metadata

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#optionsTab :

> Switch to the JDBC-based introspector.
>
> To retrieve information about database objects (DB metadata), DataGrip
> uses the following introspectors:
>
> 1. A native introspector (might be unavailable for certain DBMS). The
>    native introspector uses DBMS-specific tables and views as a source of
>    metadata. It can retrieve DBMS-specific details and produce a more
>    precise picture of database objects.
> 2. A JDBC-based introspector (available for all the DBMS). The JDBC-based
>    introspector uses the metadata provided by the JDBC driver. It can
>    retrieve only standard information about database objects and their
>    properties.
>
> Consider using the JDBC-based intorspector when the native
> introspector fails or is not available.
>
> The native introspector can fail, when your database server version is
> older than the minimum version supported by DataGrip.
>
> You can try to switch to the JDBC-based introspector to fix problems
> with retrieving the database structure information from your database.
> For example, when the schemas that exist in your database or database
> objects below the schema level are not shown in the Database tool
> window.

Comment: Works for me, when I checked the Introspect using JDBC metadata!

Comment: The "Introspect using JDBC metadata" hack is working, but you loose some aspects of the architecture, e.g. you see materialized views as regular tables... perhaps other too, but I haven't tried more for now...

Answer (score 16):

The issue is the client (`psql`) is a different version from the postgres server. I have seen this issue with psql version 11 talking to postgres version 12. To solve this issue upgrade the psql version to 12.

If you are running a docker postgres, you can exec into the container then use the psql client installed there.

```sh
# get the container id with this
docker ps
# Then exec into the container, please note the host will now be 120.0.0.1
docker exec -it c12e8c6b8eb5 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue because my psql was 9.2 and the server version was 12.7.
So ... clearly the psql client needs to be updated.  But how?

Before you go downloading/installing anything though you may already have the right version.  In my case I did.

I executed `which psql` which showed my version was coming from `/usr/bin/psql`.
I then checked `/usr/pgsql-12/bin` and found there was a psql in there.
So all I needed to do was ensure psql was picked up from there.
There are a number of places that could be controlling this; in my case I just added this line to my `.pgsql_profile` (in the postgres user's home directory):

```
export PATH="/usr/pgsql-12/bin:$PATH"
```

Logging out and back in as postgres and executing `which psql` showed the change had been successful:

```
 which psql
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/psql
```

Comment: This answer should be marked accepted

Answer (score 4):

**This answer is specific to `pgcli`**

If you are using `pgcli` you may be encountering [this issue](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/issues/1130). It's solved by updating the python package `pgspecial`.

If you installed `pgcli` using `pip`, you can simply do, depending on your python version:

```
pip install -U pgspecial
```

or

```
pip3 install -U pgspecial
```

If you are using Ubuntu and intalled `pgcli` using apt, you can either switch it to pip with:

```
sudo apt remove --purge pgcli
pip3 install pgcli
```

or update the distribution package `python-pgspecial` or `python3-pgspecial` from the [Ubuntu packages web site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sqlparse&searchon=names). In that case you may need to update its dependencies as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue today, was unable to continue work due to this, strangely the application code is working fine.

Later, found this issue is only occurring if I use OmniDb client I use to connect to DB.

I have switched client to default pgAdmin 4 that comes with postgres installation & issue is not occurring anymore pgAdmin 4. Link: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/

Its possible that OmniDb client might be older, but no time to troubleshoot it, using pgAdmin 4 for now.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For everyone looking at this answer: Since version 3.0.3 Postgres 12 support was added.

Answer (score 3):

Just update DataGrip solved this issue, Datagrip updated to version DataGrip 2019.3.3, Build #DB-193.6494.42, built on February 12, 2020, Now working :)

Just for DataGrip users!

Comment: Thanks bro. Updated datagrip from 2017 and problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today too. In my case, the problem was solved when I deleted the version 12 and installed the version 11. Seems that v12 has some features that must be create along the others columns.

Comment: You were probably using `psql` from your Postgres 11 installation to connect to Postgres 12 - you should have used `psql` for Postgres 12

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
But I found the solution by downloading the latest build on 14/10/2019
Follow the link:
https://postbird.paxa.kuber.host/2019_10_14.06_42-master-7a9e949

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, edit `Postgres.php` file and comment the lines from `hasObjectID` function as shown below.

```
function hasObjectID($table) {
    $c_schema = $this->_schema;
    $this->clean($c_schema);
    $this->clean($table);

    /*
    $sql = "SELECT relhasoids FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname='{$table}'
        AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname='{$c_schema}')";

    $rs = $this->selectSet($sql);
    if ($rs->recordCount() != 1) return null;
    else {
        $rs->fields['relhasoids'] = $this->phpBool($rs->fields['relhasoids']);
        return $rs->fields['relhasoids'];
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using PgAdmin to query the database.

Once I installed the newest version of PgAdmin the error disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

You might also try restarting pgadmin.

After upgrading from postgres96 to postgres12 I had the same issue. My pgadmin was running psql v12.0 so that wasn't the issue. I restarted pgadmin for a separate issue and the relhasoids issue went away.

If anyone could explain to me why this worked that would be appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

Just use version 11.

how to install version 11
https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-postgresql-11-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-servers/

Answer (score -3):

I also got same issue with my postgresql tables. I have fixed this issue by below query.

```
ALTER Table MyDataBase.table_name add column column_name data_type default 0 not null;
commit;
```