# How to fix “ERROR: column relhasoids does not exist” in phpPgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I'm updating a Linux server with a new version of ***PostgreSql*** and I have an Error Message in ***phpPgAdmin*** when I browse a table.

The Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server running Apache 2.4.41, PHP 7.3.11 and when I update to **PostgreSQL 12.0** and **phpPgAdmin 7.12.0** the error occurs. With PostgreSQL 11.5 and phpPgAdmin 5.6 I didn't have this problem.

I expect to visualize the data stored in the table using phpPgAdmin, but the actual output is:

```
    SQL error:
ERROR:  column «relhasoids» does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT relhasoids FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname='pr...

    In statement:
SELECT relhasoids FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname='product'
            AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname='public')
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear.  The column name `relhasoids` doesn't exist in table `pg_catalog.pg_class`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Editing the file ***/usr/share/phppgadmin/classes/database/Postgres.php*** and comment `line 1045 to line 1054`  the error disappears:

```
function hasObjectID($table) {
    $c_schema = $this->_schema;
    $this->clean($c_schema);
    $this->clean($table);
/*
    $sql = "SELECT relhasoids FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relname='{$table}'
        AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname='{$c_schema}')";

    $rs = $this->selectSet($sql);
    if ($rs->recordCount() != 1) return null;
    else {
        $rs->fields['relhasoids'] = $this->phpBool($rs->fields['relhasoids']);
        return $rs->fields['relhasoids'];
    } */
}
```

Comment: Please consider sending a patch to the phpPgAdmin developers :D

Comment: A pull request already exists--hopefully it will get committed: https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/pull/81/commits/418b7e1a4433fc71bd202604e9fd389f2acd1510

Answer (score 2):

This column does not exist anymore, since you cannot create tables with OID any longer.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html):

> WITH ( storage_parameter [= value] [, ... ] )
>
> This clause specifies optional storage parameters for a table or index; see Storage Parameters for more information. For backward-compatibility the WITH clause for a table can also include OIDS=FALSE to specify that rows of the new table should not contain OIDs (object identifiers), OIDS=TRUE is not supported anymore.
>
> WITHOUT OIDS
>
> This is backward-compatible syntax for declaring a table WITHOUT OIDS, creating a table WITH OIDS is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is because phpPgAdmin is not compatible with PostgreSQL v. 12.  PostgreSQL v. 12 has removed the `relhasoids` column because of the new way that OIDs are handled.  As of the time of this post, pgPgAdmin does not support PostgreSQL v. 12 (it is [not listed on the website](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php)).  You may need to look into alternate clients.

See also [How to fix “ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist” in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461178/how-to-fix-error-column-c-relhasoids-does-not-exist-in-postgres/58461430#58461430)