# Postgres is making a default model field [ ] locally (Rails), but when I deploy to Heroku, the field is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I made a Posts model in Rails API with a field "vouches". I want that field to default to an empty array. This works just fine locally. Here is the relevant schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_09_164230) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "vouches", default: [], array: true
  end
end
```

Locally this works great. When I create a new Post, locally my endpoint for fetching the data shows as such:

```
{
"id":1,
"title":"test",
"description":"test",
"image":null,
"vouches":[]
}
```

I deployed my app to Heroku, ran migrations. If I make the exact same post on the deployed site I get the following:

```
{
"id":1,
"title":"test",
"description":"test",
"image":null,
"vouches":null
}
```

I tried making a before_create method on the Post model that made self.vouches ||= [], to no avail. Having trouble finding other solutions that are relevant to this situation. I'm assuming this is a Postgres issue - but maybe I'm wrong on that front.

Comment: Can you add the table schema dump from Heroku Postgres as well (i.e., run ``heroku pg:psql`` and do ``\d <table>``)?

Comment: it returned:

ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...

Comment: A quick google indicates that is a mismatch between the server and ``psql`` client versions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461178/how-to-fix-error-column-c-relhasoids-does-not-exist-in-postgres). I initially thought maybe the default (``'{}'::text[]``) was somehow not set on the table, but if you can't even set the attribute to an empty array that's puzzling. Out of curiosity, what happens if you set ``vouches`` to some non-array value like a String?