# How to fix " ERROR: column t.relhasoids does not exist" in postgreSQL 12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the rails platform. After creating the DB, I had faced this issue. Does anyone have the solution to this issue?

Comment: Do you have ouststanding migrations? Run them. If not then create a new one to add the column

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461178/how-to-fix-error-column-c-relhasoids-does-not-exist-in-postgres/58462270#58462270). Short answer: check to ensure the Postgres client you are running is not older than your server version.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue while trying to describe my table(\d mytable) in the Postgres terminal. The version of the RDS server was 12.5v and psql version on the instance/machine was 10.16v. Upgraded the version on the machine by following this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu)