# ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist at character 245

Tags: postgresql

I facing the below error many times in the log file for PostgreSQL server v12.5 even the client version is the same version and I haven't any other versions now. I just was having 10 and 12.5 and I removed both of them then I reinstalled v 12.5 only. any suggestions please ?

[23939] ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist at character 245
2021-02-20 20:03:02.274 EET [23939] STATEMENT:  select n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname, a.atttypid, t.typname, a.attnum, a.attlen, a.atttypmod, a.attnotnull, c.relhasrules, c.relkind, c.oid, pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), case t.typtype when 'd' then t.typbasetype else 0 end, t.typtypmod, c.relhasoids, attidentity, c.relhassubclass from (((pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace and c.oid = 350213) inner join pg_catalog.pg_attribute a on (not a.attisdropped) and a.attnum > 0 and a.attrelid = c.oid) inner join pg_catalog.pg_type t on t.oid = a.atttypid) left outer join pg_attrdef d on a.atthasdef and d.adrelid = a.attrelid and d.adnum = a.attnum order by n.nspname, c.relname, attnum

Comment: Something is still using an outdated client library, e.g. an old JDBC driver or something similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist" in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461178/how-to-fix-error-column-c-relhasoids-does-not-exist-in-postgres)

Answer (score 2):

The query is a metadata query that has not yet got the memo that there are no more OIDs with PostgreSQL tables since v12.

Update the client software that sends these queries.